# Update t-sql table in asp.net post deployment script

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, t-sql

How can I update a table's columns with my custom values in T-SQL?

Let's say I have a table:

```
Id  |  Name  |  Currency
----+--------+-----------
1   | name1  |     $
2   | name2  |     $
3   | name3  |     €
```

I want to update each `Currency` value to `USD` or `EUR` depending on which symbol there is. So the result should look like this:

```
    Id  |  Name  |  Currency
    ----+--------+-----------
    1   | name1  |     USD
    2   | name2  |     USD
    3   | name3  |     EUR
```

How could I do this??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nikas.

You could achieve the desired output by updating the table values and using separate cases for each symbol.

```
UPDATE Currencies
SET Currency = CASE
    WHEN Currency = '$' THEN 'USD'
    WHEN Currency = '€' THEN 'EUR'
    ELSE Currency
END
WHERE
    Currency IN ('$', '€')
```

Answer (score 0):

Update your table with update statements as below:
Replace MyTable with your table name.

```
UPDATE MyTable SET Currency='USD' WHERE Currency='$';
UPDATE MyTable SET Currency='EUR' WHERE Currency='€';
```